# How can i run an if else statment from the output of a screen?

Tags: bash

for example when the terminal screen outputs a certain message you make the script do something, How do you do that?

Answer (score 1):

For doing BOTH writing to the terminal and using the output, use `tee` and then read the output into a variable with `while read var`:

```
commands | tee /dev/tty | while read var ; do
   if [ "$var" == "this" ] ; then
     echo $var is this
   else
     echo $var is that
   fi
done
```

assuming your are on a unix-like system ....

Be aware that the pipe creates a subshell!

Comment: Pretty nifty! I'm surprised that the author didn't up-vote you and mark this as resolved.